# C# WinForm created own border, resize problems

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, borderless

Just creating my first borderless WinForm-Application. To achieve the resizeability of the WinForm I used the Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575216/how-to-move-and-resize-a-form-without-a-border) (Answer from user1306322).

But everywhere I put a control to the border I lose the the ability to resize the form. Is there any possibility to fix that problem?

Comment: "Put a control to the border" surely is the problem.  You need to leave enough space between the control and the edge so that the form gets the hit test message and not the control.  In effect giving you a border back, you can make it look any way you like.  Hacking the controls so the form gets the message anyway [is technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357074/17034).

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.