# Automatically raise WM_NCHITTEST message to form WndProc

Tags: c#, winforms

Simple and short question:

I want to create a borderless resizable form. So I use the [WM_NCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message and set the result to `HTTOPLEFT`, `HTLEFT`, `...`. This works fine if I do not hover any control. But if I for example create a panel and dock it to the top, the WndProc is only called when I do not hover the panel, because the Control.WndProc of the panel is called, so `HTTOPLEFT`, `HTTOPRIGHT` and `HTTOP` are not possible anymore.

Is it possible to raise the messages to the form? I also want to support the default controls, so what I don't want to do is derive the controls and override their WndProc.

Comment: Do you have handler method that works on window?You can bind any control event to that event handler.

Comment: @SlobodanT Could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: One of the possible ways: [How to fix borderless form resize with controls on borders of the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357074/7444103)